# Is it possible to have 2 projects in 1 android?

Tags: android

I need to make one project of 2 projects. I had copied all files from 1 to other, there was no problem. But the problem is generating R file as there a different packages.

Maybe i can some how make manifest of 2 projects that there would be both projects packages.

Please correct me if on my question as i don't know how to ask this. Basically i want to make 2 manifest in one.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? I am not quite understand.

Comment: "make 2 manifest in one" -> you have to manually merge it into 1 file so that all activities, receivers, .. are withing the same application under a common packagename.

Comment: I want to add 2 projects to 1

Comment: I can merge it to 1 but i don't know how to link these 2 packages
package="com.first.main"
package="com.second.main"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert one of your project into [Android Library](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html) and use that library in your second project to merge it together as one single project.

For more info, refer to refer to android's **TicTacToe** sample project

Comment: I can't do this ,get a lot of errors. First project is not mine

Comment: do you have the source of that project? or is it an apk file?

Comment: then get that source, convert it into library project and use that project in your own project. When i say *"convert it into library project"*, it doesn't literary mean that you should convert into Library from properties under Android section. In fact you should alter (if needed) the project and then mark it as library

Comment: Then maybe you could tell me how to start an Activity of this library

Comment: you need to create an activity in your project and instead of extending it to regular *Activity* class, you'll extend to that particular activity defined in library project. Have you refereed to the TicTacToe example? its defined all there

Comment: Yap i understand it. Thanks. know it's just a problem that ebookdroid first time when app starts call class which extends Aplication. So i need to do the same from my code. Maybe you know how to do this ?

Comment: perhaps create a class in your project which extends to that application class in ebookdroid library. and dont forget to set your new defined application class in your project's manifest to use it

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, maybe you have to change the package name of two projects to the same one, then clear your project and then you will get just one R.java

There are something you have to pay attention. The package name in two "AndroidManifest.xml" file also need to be change. And you maybe want to merger two "AndroidManifest.xml" file into one and just let one of activity as MAIN.

Good luck.